# Быстрая библиотека для отрисовки графиков

Tags: график, wpf, .net

Возникла задача отрисовывать быстро изменяющийся процесс (данные приходят с датчиков по COM-порту). Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие бывают хорошие библиотеки, которые позволяют хорошо это сделать?

Фактически, задачи две, и они мало связанны друг с другом:

1. Отрисовывать нечто вроде осциллограммы, то есть динамический график с фиксированным количеством точек.
2. Отрисовать кривую всего процесса.

Если есть что-то, хотя бы частично подходящее под требования - уже было бы здорово.

PS: Пробовал `DynamicDataDisplay`. Возможно, я просто не умею его правильно использовать, но вне зависимости от количества точек он пытается перестраивать график целиком при каждом добавлении точки/серии точек. В результате всё очень тормозит. А вообще библиотека оставила самые лучшие впечатления: удобная и мощная.

Comment: А сколько примерно точек в графике, и как часто он обновляется? // Ох, некропост.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать ZedGraph.dll! Удобная в использовании и мануал понятный!